# After form submission, new data does not appear without page reload

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In my ExpressJS app I have two routes to the same location, one for 'get' and one for 'post'.

On the 'get' page it dumps all the documents from my MongoDB collection, via MongooseJS, followed by a form to add a new record to the collection.

On the 'post' page it takes in the form data and adds it to the collection, and then displays the same page you see via 'get'.

It works, but after the form is submitted the new record doesn't appear unless I reload the page. I put the code that renders the page at the very bottom, below the part that adds the data to the collection so in my mind that should work but it doesn't.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  Server.find({},
    function(err, docs) {
      if (!err){ 
          res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: docs});
      }
      else { console.log(err);}
    }
  );
}

exports.add = function(req, res){
  newServer = new Server({
    name: req.body.name,
    os: req.body.os,
    osVersion: req.body.osVersion
  });
  newServer.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
  });
  Server.find({},
    function(err, docs) {
      if (!err){ 
          res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: docs});
      }
      else { console.log(err);}
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to make this mistake over an over again with callbacks. I fixed the problem.

```
exports.add = function(req, res){
  newServer = new Server({
    name: req.body.name,
    os: req.body.os,
    osVersion: req.body.osVersion
  });
  newServer.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Server.find({},
        function(err, docs) {
          if (!err){ 
            res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: docs});
          }
          else { console.log(err);}
      }
     );
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those DB queries are async, so callbacks will solve this issue. However, you should look into using promises. Mongoose returns promises by default or you could import your library of choice. They will come in handy when dealing with nested callbacks and queries and also Error handling.